# Minio OOM(Out Of Memory) when uploading a file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, out-of-memory, minikube, minio

I have a local Kubernetes cluster inside Minikube on my Mac. I deploy a Minio standalone server as a single container with resource limits specified. When I upload a file which is larger than container memory limit, the container is terminated with reason `OOMKilled`. On Ubuntu with the same setup file is uploaded with no errors.

Minikube is running in VirtualBox and configured to use 4GB of memory. I also use Heapster and Metric Server to check memory usage over time.

```
$ minikube config set memory 4096
$ minikube addons enable heapster
$ minikube addons enable metrics-server
$ minikube start
```

[image: minikube in vb]

I use a slightly modified version of [Kubernetes confiuration for Minio standalone setup provided in Minio documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/deploy-minio-on-kubernetes.html#minio-standalone-server-deployment). I create PV and PVC for storage, Deployment and Service for Minio server. Container configuration:

- Using official Minio Docker image
- Using initContainer to create a bucket

Resource limits are set to have a Guaranteed QoS. Container is limited to 256 MB of memory and 0.5 CPU.

```
resources:
  requests:
    cpu: '500m'
    memory: '256Mi'
  limits:
    cpu: '500m'
    memory: '256Mi'
```

Full `videos-storage.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: videos-storage-pv
  labels:
    software: minio
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: /data/storage-videos/

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: videos-storage-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: ''
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      software: minio

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: videos-storage-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: videos-storage
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: videos-storage
    spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: init-minio-buckets
        image: minio/minio
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data/storage-videos
        command: ['mkdir', '-p', '/data/storage-videos/videos']
      containers:
      - name: minio
        image: minio/minio
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /data/storage-videos
        args:
        - server
        - /data/storage-videos
        env:
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          value: 'minio'
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          value: 'minio123'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: '500m'
            memory: '256Mi'
          limits:
            cpu: '500m'
            memory: '256Mi'
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /minio/health/ready
            port: 9000
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 20
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /minio/health/live
            port: 9000
          initialDelaySeconds: 5
          periodSeconds: 20
      volumes:
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: videos-storage-pv-claim

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: videos-storage-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      targetPort: 9000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: videos-storage
```

I deploy the config to the cluster:

```
$ kubectl apply -f videos-storage.yaml
```

and access Minio dashboard using Minikube, the following command opens it in browser:

```
$ minikube service videos-storage-service
```

Then I select a `videos` bucket and upload a 1 GB file. After about ~250 MB are uploaded, I get an error in Minio dashboard. Playing with limits and analyzing Heapster graphs I can see a correlation between file size and memory usage. Container uses exactly the same amount of memory equal to file size, which is weird to me. My impression is that file won't be stored directly in memory during file upload.

[image: minio dashboard error]

Describe pod

```
Name:           videos-storage-deployment-6cd94b697-p4v8n
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           minikube/10.0.2.15
Start Time:     Mon, 22 Jul 2019 11:05:53 +0300
Labels:         app=videos-storage
                pod-template-hash=6cd94b697
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             172.17.0.8
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/videos-storage-deployment-6cd94b697
Init Containers:
  init-minio-buckets:
    Container ID:  docker://09d75629a39ad1dc0dbdd6fc0a6a6b7970285d0a349bccee2b0ed2851738a9c1
    Image:         minio/minio
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://minio/minio@sha256:456074355bc2148c0a95d9c18e1840bb86f57fa6eac83cc37fce0212a7dae080
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      mkdir
      -p
      /data/storage-videos/videos
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 22 Jul 2019 11:08:45 +0300
      Finished:     Mon, 22 Jul 2019 11:08:45 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /data/storage-videos from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-zgs9q (ro)
Containers:
  minio:
    Container ID:  docker://1706139f0cc7852119d245e3cfe31d967eb9e9537096a803e020ffcd3becdb14
    Image:         minio/minio
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://minio/minio@sha256:456074355bc2148c0a95d9c18e1840bb86f57fa6eac83cc37fce0212a7dae080
    Port:          9000/TCP
    Host Port:     0/TCP
    Args:
      server
      /data/storage-videos
    State:          Running
      Started:      Mon, 22 Jul 2019 11:08:48 +0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 22 Jul 2019 11:06:06 +0300
      Finished:     Mon, 22 Jul 2019 11:08:42 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  1
    Limits:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  256Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:      500m
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   http-get http://:9000/minio/health/live delay=5s timeout=1s period=20s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get http://:9000/minio/health/ready delay=5s timeout=1s period=20s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY:  minio
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY:  minio123
    Mounts:
      /data/storage-videos from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-zgs9q (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  videos-storage-pv-claim
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-zgs9q:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-zgs9q
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

Minikube logs in `dmesg`:

```
[  +3.529889] minio invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x14000c0(GFP_KERNEL), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=-998
[  +0.000006] CPU: 1 PID: 8026 Comm: minio Tainted: G           O     4.15.0 #1
[  +0.000001] Hardware name: innotek GmbH VirtualBox/VirtualBox, BIOS VirtualBox 12/01/2006
[  +0.000000] Call Trace:
[  +0.000055]  dump_stack+0x5c/0x82
[  +0.000010]  dump_header+0x66/0x281
[  +0.000006]  oom_kill_process+0x223/0x430
[  +0.000002]  out_of_memory+0x28d/0x490
[  +0.000003]  mem_cgroup_out_of_memory+0x36/0x50
[  +0.000004]  mem_cgroup_oom_synchronize+0x2d3/0x310
[  +0.000002]  ? get_mem_cgroup_from_mm+0x90/0x90
[  +0.000002]  pagefault_out_of_memory+0x1f/0x4f
[  +0.000002]  __do_page_fault+0x4a3/0x4b0
[  +0.000003]  ? page_fault+0x36/0x60
[  +0.000002]  page_fault+0x4c/0x60
[  +0.000002] RIP: 0033:0x427649
[  +0.000001] RSP: 002b:000000c0002eaae8 EFLAGS: 00010246
[  +0.000154] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 7734 (pause) score 0 or sacrifice child
[  +0.000013] Killed process 7734 (pause) total-vm:1024kB, anon-rss:4kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Initially the problem occurred when I did not have any resource limits. When I tried to upload a big file, container with Minio would use all of the memory available in the node, and because there is no memory left, Kubernetes services become unresponsive and it started killing other containers, like `apiserver`; and file won't upload either. After that I added resource limits to Minio container and cluster itself became stable, but Minio container still dies.

I would like Minio to function within provided limits and not consume memory equal to file size. I am not sure on what side the problem might be, whether it is Minio or Minikube or VirtualBox or Docker or Kubernetes. I am not familiar with how memory works in this setup as well. As I said, the same setup worked fine on Ubuntu 18.04.

Versions:

- MacOS Mojave 10.14.5, 2.6 GHz Intel Core i5, 8 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Minikube v1.2.0
- VirtualBox 5.2.18 r124319
- kubectl v1.15.0
- Docker version 18.09.2, build 6247962
- Minio 2019-07-17T22:54:12Z (https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/minio)

Comment: You sure you enable memory limit in kernel on ubuntu?

Comment: Same question as @atline.  Minio probably upload the file to memory before writing it to disk.  Kubernetes doesn't control what happens in the container, if the service in your container writes to memory before disk, than it writes to memory before disk.  You will need to change the code within the container to effect  how much it writes to memory before disk.  This is probably a minio issue/question, and not so much to do with kubernetes, Kubernetes is behaving as expected.

Comment: @Michael Radionov you may use `docker info | grep swap` on ubuntu to confirm

Comment: @atline `docker info | grep swap` does not display anything

Comment: Then, no idea, I guess you have already update your GRUB to support limit in kernel. Wait for other folks...

Comment: @nelsonenzo Yes, I agree that Kubernetes functions correctly, it shuts down a container which has exceeded the limits and then restarts it. I guess my question is more about Minio and how it functions it this environment.

Comment: MinIO is pretty sensitive to Disk i/o, and the amount of memory required will vary accordingly.  250mb memory is probably not sufficient to keep up on your localhost, since it's reading and writing to the same disk, as well as everything else going on your box.  I woulnd't focus too much on your local macbook performance, since that's that were minio is running ultimately.  "within constraints" is subjective to resources available - which in this case I suspect is not sufficient. Try looking at your disk performance when uploading i guess is my best suggestion to "understand what's going on".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also [posted this issue to Minio repository](https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/7962), got a response that `256mb` is too low. After increasing the memory to `512mb` it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It's a shame because we are dealing with large backup files like 3GB. That means we have to reserve at least double the ram which is unutilized most of the time after the backup job has run. So it is not quite fair use when you are dealing with a client resource restricted cluster. Furthermore, it triggers metric alerts.
I wished them made it in a way to use less ram with longer upload time as a tradeoff.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).